# Confusing review audit

Tags: discussion, review, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

Today, I was reviewing a first post. In the review page, I got an answer with no username. So I thought the user may have deleted his account. The answer was great, but when I went to see the previous answers to that question, I saw an exact same answer by an old member. I thought the new user has copy pasted the answer. So, I tried to flag the answer and I got this in the review page.

> STOP! Look and Listen.
>   This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention. You didn't pass. Your review was inappropriate. This was a high quality post and you should have considered leaving it as-is or even upvoting.
>
> Don't worry, we've already handled this post appropriately – but please take a minute to look it over closely, keeping in mind the guidance above.

I understand it was for the purpose of auditing, but anyone would think that as a spam. What's the purpose of this kind of auditing?

Comment: Something something audits suck. Anyway, got a link to the answer?

Comment: @Bolt [here is the review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/2614210) and [the answer itself](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17592666/447356) - no duplicate, just highly upvoted fair answer.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn, answer was great. It was not a first post at all. The audit was judging me with that good answer. I went to that question and saw that there is an exact answer to that question by an old member. In the review page, there was no user name. So, I tried to flag the answer. I mean this kind of auditing is confusing. Am I clear or making things more confusing?

Comment: @sakibmoon: You mean it was really that answer by an old member, but simply disguised as a duplicate answer by a new member, right?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, I have probably confused everyone with this question. I am not saying that the answer should have been flagged. The answer was ok, but I believed that, a new user copy pasted the upvoted answer as there was no user name in the review page. So, I tried to flag the answer.

Comment: @sakibmoon you got me confused, yes. What new user? There is no other answer similar to the answer I linked to, which is the audit source.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn, yes that's right. Any new reviewer would think that and old reviewer won't have to face that. So, what's the purpose of this kind of reviewing?

Comment: @sakibmoon: No idea. I do agree that these audits are confusing.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, edited my question.

Comment: Assuming you went to the question to see other answers and you saw the same answer by what appears to be other user it usually means you're facing a review audit. Either skip if you're not sure, or upvote in case of highly upvoted answer.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I get that now, but for a new reviewer it would mean an duplicate answer. My point is this kind of auditing is useless.

Comment: On the contrary: the audit has taught you something new and that's its purpose after all. Just be more careful next time and generally when reviewing. No harm done.

Comment: Say, does the review audit hide the vote score too? It's been a while since I've encountered a "First Posts" review audit so I don't remember.

Comment: Interesting; this is the first audit that I've seen that was for a good post. Is this a recent change?

Comment: @ChrisForrence Yes, relatively recent.

Comment: @michaelb958 - Ah, ok. I usually open the flag dialog to check if it was an audit, then actually do the review. By opening the flag dialog, however, I got dinged for trying to flag a good answer. I need to be on the lookout fully now ;)

Comment: @ChrisForrence I think that's the point of these new audits...

Comment: @OldCheckmark yes it auto hide the vote score too.